# derive strong password from hash

Tags: javascript, passwords, password-protection

I am crypto newb, looking to avoid blunder. I have read quite a bit on deterministic password generation. I have a scheme I feel fairly comfortable with. Looking for help on one of the components.

Firstly, I plan on using scrypt for the master password. I also have other unique inputs that will be combined with the scrypt output to create the final password derivative. I'm focused here on the question of how to adhere to different password requirement schemes. Below is a function that can be run in jsfiddle. It should output a generated password and the number of iterations required to match the requirements. I can store the 3 tuple of character requirements for the password scheme, the input parameters, and the number of iterations required. I hope this is strong and can avoid bruit forcing. I was unsure how to generate caps, and special characters via typical hex hash conversion, below is what i think works but I am not sure what attacks it may be subject to.

- Commenting out the padding seems like it creates some issues?
- Is there any issue converting to octal (am i losing randomness?) and then to a char?

sample code

```
var input_secret = "e"
var max_it = 1000
var special_chars = 10
var digit_chars = 6
var cap_chars = 4

function hex2a(hexx) {
    var hex = hexx.toString();//force conversion
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2){
      str += //String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
      String.fromCodePoint(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));
    }
    return str;
}

function sha256(str, it) {
  if (it > max_it){
    throw new Error("can't find a match to satisfy regex");
  }
  console.log("iteration: ",it)
  // We transform the string into an arraybuffer.
  var buffer = new TextEncoder("utf-8").encode(str);
  return crypto.subtle.digest("SHA-256", buffer).then(function (hash) {
    var t = hex(hash)
    if (!reg.test(t) && it < max_it){
        console.log("failed requirements",t)
      var new_it = it + 1
      return sha256(t,new_it)
    } else if(it >= max_it){
        console.log("HORROR")
        return false      
    }
    else{
      return [t,it]
    }

  });
}

var reg_string = '(?=(.*(\\`|\\~|\\!|\\@|\\#|\\$|\\%|\\^\|\\*|\\(|\\|\\-)){'+special_chars+'})(?=(.*\\d){'+digit_chars+'})(?=.*[a-z])(?=(.*[A-Z]){'+cap_chars+'}).{14,14}'

var reg = new RegExp(reg_string)
console.log("regexp",reg)

function hex(buffer) {
  var hexCodes = [];
  var view = new DataView(buffer);
  for (var i = 0; i < view.byteLength; i += 4) {
    // Using getUint32 reduces the number of iterations needed (we process 4 bytes each time)
    var value = view.getUint32(i)
    // toString(16) will give the hex representation of the number without padding
    var stringValue = value.toString(8)

    // We use concatenation and slice for padding
    //var padding = '00000000'
    var padding = ''
    var paddedValue = (padding + hex2a(stringValue)).slice(-padding.length)
    hexCodes.push(paddedValue);
  }

  // Join all the hex strings into one
  return hexCodes.join("");
}



console.log("Input 'e' should take 454 iterations to satisfy 10 special, 6 digits, and 4 caps");
sha256(input_secret,1).then(function(res) {
    var digest = res[0]
  var iterations = res[1]
  var printable_digest = digest.replace(/[^\x20-\x7E]+/g, '');
console.log([[special_chars,digit_chars,cap_chars],printable_digest,iterations]);
  console.log("test",reg.test(printable_digest))
});
```